# How to add zero to single digit number(time)?

Tags: python, string, list

I have list with numbers separated with colons. I need to add zero if number is single.
For example `nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:0"]`

I've seen some recommendation to use `zfill()` but I am not sure how to use it.

What I need:
`nums = ["10:30", "09:30", "11:00"]`

Comment: Those look more like times that numbers

Comment: How should you interpret `"11:3"` ?

Comment: 11:3 would be 11:30, just need the leading zero

Comment: @Code34 that's not a leading zero now is it

Comment: yes, I know what you mean, small language barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to pad zeros to strings, e.g. to pad to the left:

```
>>> nums = ['10:30', '9:30', '11:0']
>>> ['{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(*n.split(':')) for n in nums]
['10:30', '09:30', '11:00']
```

Alternatively, converting strings to numbers:

```
>>> ['{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*map(int, n.split(':'))) for n in nums]
['10:30', '09:30', '11:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using string formatting:

```
def add_zeros(item: str) -> str:
    nums = item.split(":")
    formatted_item = ":".join(f"{int(num):02d}" for num in nums)
    return formatted_item
```

Then apply it to each item in your list:

```
nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:0"]
[add_zeros(num) for num in nums]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution utilizing `zfill` & `ljust`

```
nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:0"]

fixed = []
for t in nums:
    x, y = t.split(':')
    fixed.append(x.zfill(2) + ':' + y.ljust(2, '0'))

print(fixed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to think this through a bit, because like mentioned in the commends 11:3 could be 11:03 or 11:30, but none the less, using actual datetime in python you can do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:3"]
x = [datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M').strftime('%H:%M') for x in nums]

>>> x
['10:30', '09:30', '11:03']
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to add zero if number is single

Using list comprehension

```
nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:0"]

nums_added = [ i + "0" if len(i.split(":")[1]) == 1 else i for i in nums]

print(nums_added)
```

Output:

```
['10:30', '9:30', '11:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution leaning the fact that these look **a lot** like dates could be ...

Set up your list

```
nums = ["10:30", "9:30", "11:0"]
```

Iterate through the list converting, grabbing the time and lopping off (technical term) the last 3 characters

```
for item in nums:
    print(str(datetime.strptime(item, '%H:%M').time())[:-3])
```

Output from print

```
10:30
09:30
11:00
```